# Basecamp API time entries of single user

Tags: php, xml, curl, basecamp

To access time entries of single project i just use `https://{*}.basecamphq.com/projects/{project_id}/time_entries.xml`
, but i want to take time entries for a single user. Official documentation says

### Get report

- `GET /time_entries/report.xml` return the set of time entries that match the given criteria.

This action accepts the following query parameters: `from`, `to`, `subject_id`, `todo_item_id`, `filter_project_id`, and `filter_company_id`. The `subject_id` parameter lets you constrain the result to a single person’s time entries.

But where i should put this criterias?

```
https://{*}.basecamphq.com/time_entries/report.xml?subject_id={person_id}
```

gives me nothing.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was found!

```
https://{*}.basecamphq.com/time_entries/report.xml?from=20120707&to=20120920&subject_id=9652173
```

It works! So, as i understand, if you want to use one of the criterias, you also must declare "from" and "to" criterias.